# Reuse an operator<< for several classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two classes (this is a, extract from my actual more complex case)

```
class ClUInt {
public:
    ClUInt() : _i(2), _arr{1,2,3} {};
    ClUInt(const unsigned int ui) : _i(ui) {};
private:
    unsigned int _i;
    double _arr[3];
};

class ClInt {
public:
    ClInt() : _i(-2), _arr{-1,-2,-3} {};
    ClInt(const int i) : ClInt() { _i = i; };
private:
    int _i;
    double _arr[3];
};
```

They are very similar, but one uses `int` and the other `unsigned int` for member `_i`.

I want to overload `operator<<` with, e.g.,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ClInt & ci)
{
    cout << ci._i << endl;
    cout << ci._arr[0] << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Assume I want the "same" overload for both classes.

**How can I write it only once, so it is easier to maintain?**
I thought of defining my own cast, but I am not sure it is the way to go...

Notes:

1. I *think* I have no chance of making the two classes share any part of an inheritance tree.
2. They could actually be `struct`s, so if privacy affects the answer, one can assume `_i` and `_arr` are `public`.
3. In the actual case, the two `struct`s have a larger number of "common" members which are signed/unsigned, respectively.

Comment: Seems like you could merge both classes in a single class template.Is this an option?

Comment: @churill - Still pending on some definitions... I am not certain.

Answer (score 3):

Use a template with concepts:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
concept ClInteger = std::same_as<T, ClInt> || std::same_as<T, ClUInt>;

template <ClInteger T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T & ci)
{
    std::cout << ci._i << '\n';
    std::cout << ci._arr[0] << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Note that this operator must be the friend of those classes to have access to their private fields.
[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4vWx4y)

Comment: note - this is not in any published standard yet, but scheduled for C++20

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a templated `operator<<` which works for only those two types using SFINAE. E.g.:

```
template <class T,
  std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_same<ClInt, std::decay_t<T>>::value
      or std::is_same<ClUInt, std::decay_t<T>>::value
    , int> = 0>
std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & out, T const & obj) {
  out << obj._i << '\n';
  out << obj._arr[0] << '\n';
  return out;
}
```

The above example is for C++14, but can be made to work with C++11 if you replace things like `std::decay_t<T>` with `typename std::decay<T>::type`.

Note: I replaced `std::endl` with `'\n'`, since you probably don't want to be flushing your output stream every time. See [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Comment: is the `decay_t` necessary?

Comment: note that the SFINAE condition can be given its own name which will help with readability and reuse, i.e. `template<typename T> using IsClXInt = std::enable_if_t< ..... >;` and then `template<class T, typename = IsClXInt<T>> std::ostream& operator<<` ...

Comment: @M.M I messed around in Godbolt a little and for the few cases I tried the `std::decay_t` seemed to be redundant indeed. I was thinking T could be e.g. `ClInt const &`, but it seems the reference and const "collapsing" is done before/during determining what "T" is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just coincidence, but your two classes share a lot. So, why not turn them into templates:

```
template<typename integer_type>
class IntegerClass
{
    /// ... further code elided

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, IntegerClass const& obj)
    {
        return out
            << obj._i << endl
            << obj._arr[0] << endl;
    }
    integer_type _i;
    double _arr[3];
};

// optional typedefs
// These are a matter of taste, not actually mine.
typedef IntegerClass<unsigned int> ClUInt;
typedef IntegerClass<signed int> ClInt;
```

Comment: One of the `struct`s is `struct sysinfo`, from header `sys/sysinfo.h`. I guess I cannot make it part of a template.
The other `struct` is written by me.